# How to get IEnumerable(Of DataRow) From DataTable query

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, ienumerable

All the examples I have found of complex grouping of `DataTable` results that use linq query commands look to have no problems getting an `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)` object as the result.

However I seem to only get a `AnonymousType Enumerator` return that I cannot cast to `DataTable`.

I have workarounds, but would prefer to convert the results to a `DataTable`, as it looks possible and I may be doing something wrong.

It's a simple table with Many `ClientID` and `ClientName` columns and other columns with login timestamps.

```
Dim dtMatrix As DataTable = New DataTable()
```

... (populate DataTable)

```
Dim qClients = From row In dtMatrix 
  Group row By client = New With {Key .ClientID = row("ClientID"), Key .ClientName = row("ClientName")} Into Group 
  Select New With {Key .ClientID = client.ClientID, Key .ClientName = client.ClientName}
```

This returns the generic Enumerator result, however

```
Dim qClients As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = From row In dtMatrix 
  Group row By client = New With {Key .ClientID = row("ClientID"), Key .ClientName = row("ClientName")} Into Group 
  Select New With {Key .ClientID = client.ClientID, Key .ClientName = client.ClientName}
```

Throws an exception

> Unable to cast object of type... to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Data.DataRow]'.

I will be happy to paste the whole error message if it will add more clarity.

My base assumption is that the `DataTable` should allow the cast to occur inherently as it is the object being queried.  However this does not seem to be the case.  Have I constructed my query incorrectly?  (Framework 4.6.2)

Comment: You select an anonymous type. Of course this is not castable to a DataRow. But the question is, do you really need DataRows as result? What you are doing with it?

Comment: Hi Tim,  especially it has a wider scope of usability in future projects.  DataTables are used extensively through the company's many solutions.  Many of the custom tools take DataTables as a constructor parameter etc etc... Being able to use linq to do some of the complex work will allow the ability to reduce the number of stored procs. That's the main reason in a nutshell.

Comment: Thanks Mat - certainly an improvement.

Comment: _"Being able to use linq to do some of the complex work will allow the ability to reduce the number of stored procs"_ But Linq-To-DataTable is not a replacement for SP's. You already have to have all data  in memory to be able to query the DataTable. Stored-Procedures can query the database and only return the result, so they are much more efficient,

Comment: Completely agree that SPs are more efficient, no arguments there.  However, for example when creating a Table with headings, summary info etc, calling one SP once and manipulating the returned data in memory to provide multiple information tit bits is less clutter than 3 or more SPs and possbily multiple DB calls.  As I mentioned before I have workarounds for what I am ultimately trying to achieve, whose efficiency can be debated till the cows come home - however I would find value in being able to work with a IEnumerable(DataRow) result from a linq Query, which is the reason for my question.

Comment: Have you looked at this extension which enables to use `CopyToDataTable` on any type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/implement-copytodatatable-where-type-not-a-datarow ?

Comment: I have, infact the CopyToDataTable DataTableExtensions function is the exact reason I am trying to get an IEnumerable(Of DataRow) returned.  As per the link you sent "The CopyToDataTable methods, however, only operate on an IEnumerable<T> source where the generic parameter T is of type DataRow".  As per another forum that I have posted the same question the only suggestion I have received so far is to build my own CopyToDataTable function, which I have done and it works.  However I believe it should would inherently within the framework and am going to struggle to sleep until I figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167337/discussion-between-daniel-moore-and-tim-schmelter).

Comment: `dtMatrix.AsEnumerable()` would return IEnumerable of DataRow

Comment: Hi Magnus, yes it does, if we perform a simple select e.g. `Dim qClients2 As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = (From row In dtMatrix.AsEnumerable Where row("ClientID") = 1 Select row)` the result object is Of DataRow - however as soon as the grouping is added to the linq the result object becomes Anonymous - defying my understanding (limited albeit) of inheritance logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OfType` on the `Rows` property of the `DataTable`:

```
Dim dtMatrix As DataTable = New DataTable()
'' Populate code goes here...

Dim dtRows As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = dtMatrix.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)()
```

The [`Rows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rows?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_DataTable_Rows) property returns a [`DataRowCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection?view=netframework-4.7.1), that implements (through inheritance) the `IEnumerable` interface but not the `IEnumerable(Of T)` interface, that's why you can't use most of linq over it directly.

Comment: Hi Zohar, thanks for the suggestion.  OfType(Of DataRow)() returns the same Enumerator as dtMatrix.AsEnumerable.  I have tested both variations in the linq function and the DataRow datatype seems to be discarded with the grouping for one reason or another.  The code I tested was - From row In dtMatrix.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)() Group row By...   It returned the Anonymous Type as per the parent dtMatrix did.

Comment: Interestingly - if I remove the grouping, your explanation holds true.  The code: -  `Dim qClients2 As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = (From row In dtMatrix.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)() Where row("ClientID") = 1 Select row)` - works

Comment: Yes. `DataTable.AsEnumerable()` returns the same thing as `DataTable.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)()`. I suspect that the problem is the fact that your last `select` is not selecting a DataRow but an anonymous type.

Comment: I would say you are 100% correct.  The group object (which is anonymous type) seems to the object that is what Linq migrates to as part of the way it crunches the grouping.  Thank you for placing me back on the path of digestible logic.  I still cannot get the query to return a IEnurmerable(of DataRow) but will continue trying different combinations.  One thing I have learnt though with the anonymous types is that the intelisense in VS is awesome and dynamically allows you to access the inline properties after syntactically declaring the anon type - that is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The following extension uses Reflection to create a new `DataTable` and create `DataColumn`s in it that match the properties and fields of the type passed in. In general, if you are creating anonymous types in LINQ, you can't just convert to a `DataRow` which must be tied to a `DataTable` which must already have matching columns. I went ahead and wrote a second extension to `DataTable` that adds an `IEnumerable<T>` with matching field/property names to it.

```
Public Module Ext
    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetValue(member As MemberInfo, srcObject As Object) As Object
        If TypeOf member Is FieldInfo Then
            Return DirectCast(member, FieldInfo).GetValue(srcObject)
        ElseIf TypeOf member Is PropertyInfo Then
            Return DirectCast(member, PropertyInfo).GetValue(srcObject)
        Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", Nameof(member))
        End If
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetMemberType(member As MemberInfo) As Type
        If TypeOf member Is FieldInfo Then
            Return DirectCast(member, FieldInfo).FieldType
        ElseIf TypeOf member Is PropertyInfo Then
            Return DirectCast(member, PropertyInfo).PropertyType
        ElseIf TypeOf member Is EventInfo Then
            Return DirectCast(member, EventInfo).EventHandlerType
        Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or EventInfo", Nameof(member))
        End If
    End Function    

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToDataTable(Of T)(rows As IEnumerable(Of T)) As DataTable
        Dim dt = New DataTable
        If (rows.Any()) Then
            Dim rowType = rows.First().GetType()
            Dim memberInfos = rowType.GetProperties.Cast(Of MemberInfo)().Concat(rowType.GetFields).ToArray()
            For Each info In memberInfos
                dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(info.Name, info.GetMemberType()))
            Next

            For Each r In rows
                dt.Rows.Add(memberInfos.Select(Function (i) i.GetValue(r)).ToArray())
            Next
        End If
        Return dt
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function AddObjects(Of T)(dt As DataTable, rows As IEnumerable(Of T))
        If (rows.Any()) Then
            Dim rowType = rows.First().GetType()
            Dim memberInfos = rowType.GetProperties().Cast(Of MemberInfo)().Concat(rowType.GetFields()).ToArray()

            For Each r In rows
                Dim newRow = dt.NewRow()
                For Each memberInfo In memberInfos
                    newRow(memberInfo.Name) = memberInfo.GetValue(r)
                Next

                dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
            Next
        End If
        Return dt
    End Function
End Module
```

Note that I write in C# and translated this from my C# extension. It is untested but compiles.

Using the extension, you should be able to get a `DataTable` from your `qClients` by:

```
Dim dtClients = qClients.ToDataTable()
```

Comment: Thanks NetMage, I had written a rudimentary function that did something similar - however yours is much more sophisticated in that its very generic and can be used universally, possibly in it's own helper DLL with a few other handy functions.  I was hoping that it would work inherently within the framework, however it seems the SELECT will generate the return Enumerable based on the GROUP BY Object's inherited base.  With all the examples that had CopyToDataTable suffixed, without testing, I can only assume the earlier frameworks compiled the linq statement differently - MS decided to chng it?